# Webkit Line Clamp truncates link in the middle

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a link

```
<div class="module line-clamp">
   <a href='some url' target="_self">some really long text</a>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
.module {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.line-clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

I wanted to truncate this after 3 lines of text and put an ellipsis at the end like this

```
some
really
long ...
```

What actually happens is

```
some
really ...
text
```

If I change my html to be

```
<div class="module line-clamp">
   <p>some really long text</p>
</div>
```

then I do get

```
some
really
long ...
```

What am I missing?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s48xkeke/2/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully, this helps someone in the future with a similar problem.

There was a simple solution to this simple problem.  I put a p tag around the text of the anchor

```
<div class="module line-clamp">
   <a href='some url' target="_self"><p>some really long text</p></a>
</div>
```

Comment: a put `<span>` around because `<p>` can add some unwanted margin around

Answer (score 5):

After reading Sachin's answer I tried adding an empty :after pseudo element and it also did the trick:

```
.line-clamp a:after { content: ""; }
```

Comment: This answer helped me. Thanks, Fredrik.
I wonder why adding a pseudo element to `a` element also prevent the bug on Safari...
Do you have any clue by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in some old version webkit browser.Just remove the "href" of the tag "a",or do not set the "-webkit-line-clamp" for the tag "a".The new  version of the chrome has fixed the bug.

Comment: This is really so. Can you give a link to the resource which expands on this?